# get the name of the element on which I `clicked` / `mousedown`

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a page whose root element is a Grid named `Root`.

I have many controls like `TextBlock`, `TextBox`, `Grid`, `Rectangle`, `Border` etc... who are children of `Root`.

Now, I want to have a `MouseDown` or `PreviewMouseDown` or `Click` on `Root` to find the name of the element on which I clicked.

So, how can I get the name of the element on which I `clicked` / `mousedown` ?

If I can get a solution that uses Tunneling, It will be much easier.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[RoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.routedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has property Source that  Gets or sets a reference to the object that raised the event. Try this

> xaml.cs

```
private void Grid_MouseDown_1(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var mouseWasDownOn = e.Source as FrameworkElement;
        if (mouseWasDownOn != null)
        {
            string elementName = mouseWasDownOn.Name;
        }
    }
```

> xaml

```
<Grid PreviewMouseDown="Grid_MouseDown_1">
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}"/>
        <Button Content="ok"/>
    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

Khushi sara project stackoverflow walon se he karana hai kya :)

Comment: Nahi, sara project stackoverflow walo se nahi karwana. And by the way I am working on same problem from last 3 - 4 days.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question once again.

Comment: Being true this is not the way to solve that problem .I am sure what you trying to do is you will go through all elements except the one where MouseDown happen and will change there background to transparent. Suppose if there are many and many elements you will iterate them on every mousedown . and also dont forget to write e.Handled=true ; at the end otherwise it will keep down tunnelling and u will be iterating again and again