# Why is event not firing in WPF/MVVM application?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, devexpress, prism-4

I have the following NavBar, with the `Content` data template marked up as follows:

```
<dxn:NavBarControl Name="SideMenuNavBar" DataContext="{Binding}" IsEnabled="{Binding Enabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Bars}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="1">
  <dxn:NavBarControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="dxn:NavBarGroup">
      <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DisplayText}"/>
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding MenuItems}"/>
      <Setter Property="DisplaySource" Value="Content"/>
      <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
              <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildItems}" DataType="{x:Type common:MenuItemBase}">
                  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemText}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                      <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuText}" Click="MenuItem_OnClick" />
                      </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                  </TextBlock>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
              </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            </TreeView>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </dxn:NavBarControl.Resources>
  <dxn:NavBarControl.View>
    <dxn:NavigationPaneView GroupDisplayMode="Text" ItemDisplayMode="Text" MaxVisibleGroupCount="12"/>
  </dxn:NavBarControl.View>
</dxn:NavBarControl>
```

The binding is working, as my one treeview of menu items appears correctly, yet when I click (`MouseDown` event) nothing happend, or when I double click, for the following handler, the handler does not execute:

```
private void Control_OnMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var x = sender;
}
```

My breakpoint on `var x = sender;` never gets hit.

NOTE: I know I should not be using events but rather commands, or some other much less coupled code, but I urgently need to demo what happens when the user clicks a menu item, and before the event, my code for a command didn't fire either. What could be wrong here?

Comment: where do you register the MouseDown-Event? I only the the Click-Event of MenuItem

Comment: What Version of DevExpress are you using?

Comment: @Jehof 13.2 right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite new to WPF, and very new to the DevExpress WPF suite, so I just copied the original code above from an example somewhere. Then I thought to myself, why a `ContextMenu`? Then, I right clicked the menu item, and a blank context menu item appeared, and that fired the event. I removed the bloody context menu, and now my menu item is firing the event, like I wanted when I asked this question. The new structure of the `TreeView` is as follows:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ChildItems}" DataType="{x:Type menus:MenuItemBase}">
    <MenuItem DataContext="{Binding}" Header="{Binding ItemText}" Click="MenuItem_OnClick" />
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

I'm still trying to get proper command binding working, but this answers my question about the events.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: `ContextMenu` is completly outside of your Controls `VisualTree` so normal Binding won't work at all unless you change your Binding as descibed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033522/wpf-contextmenu-woes-how-do-i-set-the-datacontext-of-the-contextmenu)

Since you are using a code Behind Event try the following:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuText}" MouseDown="MenuItem_MouseDown" />
```

And

```
private void MenuItem_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
  var x = sender;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should you Command Binding, ensuring you bind to the same context where the command is created.

If `<MenuItem Header="{Binding MenuText}" ...>` is binding correctly, than you should create a RelayCommand in the same context. and then bind to the click via

`<MenuItem Click="{Binding ClickCommand}" ...?`

But if you need a quickfix, you could use PreviewMouseButtonDown/Up in your NavBarControl and then check what was click in the handler?

See: [get the name of the element on which I `clicked` / `mousedown`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930759/get-the-name-of-the-element-on-which-i-clicked-mousedown)

```
<dxn:NavBarControl PreviewMouseUp="NavBar_PreviewMouseUp" ...>
```

And in the code behind.

```
private void NavBar_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var mouseWasUpOn = e.Source as MenuItem;
    if (mouseWasUpOn != null)
    {
        string header = mouseWasDownOn.Header;
    }
}
```

But do note, this is just a workaround if the normal event handlers are not working. Ideally you should be binding to a Command!

Comment: Yeah, I know, thanks, but the boss wanted to see if the menu click correctly opened a Delphi window in the proper area of the view. Once I got the `Click` event working, the other stuff was quite easy.

Comment: I have tried using a command as you say, but instead a `DelegateCommand` and I get an `InvalidCastException`:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'."

I can't find a `RelayCommand` class.